# Making a block of code run more than once c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a simple programming language in c# to allow users to input commands in a textbox and draw shapes onto the screen, I have written a method to do this. The trouble I am having is that the method is only drawing one shape at a time even though i am giving it two commands.

```
public void RunProgram()
    {
        try
        {
            string[] spilt = cp.UserCMD(textInput).Split('(', ')', ','); // spilts on brackets to get numbs inside of brackets
            foreach (string cmd in spilt) //spilt string on brackets and comma 
            {
                if (cp.ValidCommand(textInput) == true) //checks if command is valid
                {
                    if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "reset".ToLower())
                    {
                        x = 0; 
                        y = 0;
                    }
                    else if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "moveTo".ToLower())
                    {
                        x = Int32.Parse(spilt[1]); //gets x and y from 2nd and 3rd element of spilt array. 1st item is command
                        y = Int32.Parse(spilt[2]);

                    }
                    else if (cmdInput == "clear".ToLower())
                    {
                        ClearForm();
                    }
                }

                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "circle".ToLower())
                {
                    radius = Int32.Parse(spilt[1]); ////gets radius from 2nd element of spilt array. 1st item is command
                }
                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "rectangle".ToLower())
                {
                    width = Int32.Parse(spilt[1]); //gets width and height from 2nd and 3rd element of spilt array. 1st item is command
                    height = Int32.Parse(spilt[2]);
                }
                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "triangle".ToLower())
                {
                    side1 = Int32.Parse(spilt[1]); //gets sides 2nd and 3rd and 4th element of spilt array. 1st item is command
                    side2 = Int32.Parse(spilt[2]);
                    side3 = Int32.Parse(spilt[3]);

                }

            }

            Graphics g;
            g = Graphics.FromImage(drawOutput);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);

            if (cp.ValidCommand(textInput) == true) // check if command is valid 
            {
                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "circle".ToLower())
                {
                    circle.drawCircle(radius, pen, g, x, y); // draw circle using x and y from spilt array
                    setImage(g);

                }
                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "rectangle".ToLower())
                {
                    rect.drawRectangle(width, height, pen, g, x, y); // draw rect from width and height from spilt array
                    setImage(g);
                }
                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "triangle".ToLower())
                {
                    tri.drawTriangle(side1, side2, side3, pen, g); // draw triangle from 3 different sides from spilt array
                    setImage(g);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have a syntax error, Please check your command"); //if command is not valid then throw 
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have a syntax error, Please check your parameters \nError: \n" + e1); // displays messagebox if correct parameters are not given
        }

    }
```

The code above is the method being called. And the code is when i loop through the lines in the text box.

```
if (cmdInput == "run".ToLower())
        {
            foreach (var line in InputTxtBox.Lines)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);

                RunProgram();
            }
        }

        if (cmdInput != "run".ToLower())
        {
            textInput = CMDBox.Text;
            RunProgram();
        }
```

If the user types in:
   circle(100)
   rectange(100,100)

The expected outcome should be a circle and rectangle drawn on screen however at the moment only a circle would be drawn and not the rectangle

Comment: is it drawing the first shape or the second shape?

Comment: it is drawing only the first shape

Comment: How is your `line` in your `foreach` that is being assigned each command referenced in your `RunProgram` method?

Comment: it isn't, i was under the impression that the foreach would run the method for every line in the textbox, the command is coming from a different method

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem lies within you foreach loop. First make sure that your text box is multiline enabled.

`foreach (var line in InputTxtBox.Lines.Count())` should loop through for the amount of lines are input in the textbox.

```
 foreach (var line in InputTxtBox.Lines.Count())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);

                RunProgram();
            }
```